# How to list all whatsapp templates in twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I've read the documentation from Twilio API but there is no item to simple list the whatsapp templates in my account. I've tried search here even in chatgpt but I can't list my templates.

I have three templates aproved from whatsapp and I even can send messages with my credentials, my senders is configured, my SID, account Id and Authkey.

[image: Aproved template]

Comment: The screen you show in the screenshot should list all templates you submitted. Or are you looking for an API which returns all templates?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for an API to return all templates I have.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all templates from your account via API, follow the information about the request that you need to do:

- URL: https://messaging.twilio.com/v1/Channels/WhatsApp/Templates
- Method: GET
- Authorization: Basic Auth
- Username: Account SID
- Password: Auth token

It'll return an object like this:

```json
{
"whatsapp_templates": [...],
"meta": {...}
}
```

I hope that it can help you! :D

Answer (score 1):

The Twilio team resolved my ticket with the beta Doc API, they released one API to GET all templates in your service.

Comment: Can you share the api call?